# Elevating NodeJS ChildProcess created with child_process.fork()

Tags: node.js, child-process, elevated-privileges

I'm developing an electron application which downloads software. For users who target "Program Files" however, the installation needs to run with administrator permissions.

I'm creating a child process in which the installer runs using child_process.fork(), and am depending on the IPC connection for the ability to send and receive messages.

Unfortunately however, I can't find any way to elevate this process. Some libraries (such as node-windows) use child_process.exec() under the hood, but this doesn't create the IPC connection.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option is to run the whole app as administrator.
You can force (or, politically correct,*remind*) user to run as admin.
E.g. in [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) with `"requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"`

If you want to elevate only child process, you can either make this child process smart enough to ask for elevation, or use an 'elevator', extra program which will ask for the elevation.

[Node-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/) does that with [VBS script](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/tree/master/bin/elevate)

[electron-react-boileplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) does that with pre-compiled program [elevate](https://github.com/jpassing/elevate)

Also [node-powershell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-powershell) supports executing commands, if necessary, with elevation (basic powershell).

As for IPC, what are you after? `child_process.exec` buffers the output, while `child_proces.spawn` gives it to you in a stream-like manner (see [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))

You just need to provide a callback with the correct arguments.
Example from [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html):

```
const { exec, spawn } = require('child_process');
exec('my.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```